# Crontab not restarting process

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to setup a crontab to run 6 python data scrapers. I am tired of having to restart them manually when one of them fails. When running the following:

```
>  ps -ef | grep python
ubuntu   31537     1  0 13:09 ?  00:00:03 python /home/ubuntu/scrapers/datascraper1.py
```

etc...   I get a list of the datascrapers 1-6 all in the same folder.

I edited my crontab like this:

> sudo crontab -e

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * pgrep -f /home/ubuntu/scrapers/datascraper1.py || python /home/ubuntu/scrapers/datascraper1.py > test.out
```

Then I hit control+X to exit and hit yes to save as  /tmp/crontab.M6sSxL/crontab .
However it does not work in restarting or even starting datascraper1.py whether I kill the process manually or if the process fails on its own. Next, I tried reloading cron but it still didn't work:

```
sudo cron reload
```

Finally I tried removing nohup from the cron statement and that also did not work. 
How can I check if a cron.allow or cron.deny file exists?
Also, do I need to add a username before pgrep? I am also not sure what the "> test.out" is doing at the end of the cron statement.

After running

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

to check to see if cron ran at all, I get this output:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-12:~$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Jan  5 07:01:01 ip-172-31-29-12 CRON[31101]: (root) CMD (pgrep -f datascraper1.py ||       
python /home/ubuntu/scrapers/datascraper1.py > test.out)
Jan  5 07:01:01 ip-172-31-29-12 CRON[31100]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan  5 07:17:01 ip-172-31-29-12 CRON[31115]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  5 08:01:01 ip-172-31-29-12 CRON[31140]: (root) CMD (pgrep -f datascraper1.py || python /home/ubuntu/scrapers/datascraper1.py > test.out)
```

Since there is evidence of Cron executing the command, there must be something wrong with this command, (note: I added the path to python):

```
pgrep -f datascraper1.py || /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/scrapers/datascraper1.py > test.out
```

Which is supposed to check to see if datascaper1.py is running, if not then restart it.

Since Cron is literally executing this statement:

```
(root) CMD (pgrep -f datascraper1.py || python /home/ubuntu/scrapers/datascraper1.py > test.out)
```

aka

```
root pgrep -f datascraper1.py
```

Running the above root command gives me:

```
The program 'root' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install root-system-bin
```

Is there a problem with Cron running commands from root?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the new cron line?

Comment: I would like to first check to see if the program /home/ubuntu/scrapers/datascraper1.py is running, then to restart it if it is not running.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to see if cron is working at all.
Add this to your cron file (and ideally delete the python statement for now, to have a clear state)

```
* * * * * echo `date` >>/home/your_username/hello_cron
```

This will output the date in the file "hello_cron" every minute. Try this, and if this works, ie you see output every minute, write here and we can troubleshoot further.

You can also look in your system logs to see if cron has ran your command, like so:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Btw the >test.out part would redirect the output of the python program to the file test.out. I am not sure why you need the nohup part - this would let the python programs run even if you are logged out - is this what you want?

EDIT: After troubleshooting cron:

The message about no MTA installed means that cron is trying to send you an e-mail with the output of the job but cannot because you dont have an email programm installed:

Maybe this will fix it:
    sudo apt-get install postfix

The line invoking the python program in cron is producing some output (an error) so it's in your best interests to see what happens. Look at this tutorial to see how to set your email address: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-crontab-change-mailto-settings/

Just in case the tutorial becomes unavailable:

```
MAILTO:youremail@example.com
```

Comment: See updated output, it appears that CRON is trying to run every minute but the syslog just says (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: I have heard other people say they need to add a path to python in Cron, how would I do that?

Comment: do 'which python' in bash, and you should have the path of your python executable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add python home to your path at the start of the job, however you have python set up. When you're running it yourself and you type python, it checks where you are, then one level down, then your $PATH. So, python home (where the python binary is) needs to be globally exported for the user that owns the cron (so, put it in a rc script in /etc/rc.d/) or, you need to append the python home to path at the start of the cron job. So,

```
 export PATH=$PATH:<path to python>
```

Or, write the cron entry as

```
 /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/etc/etc
```

to call it directly. It might not be /usr/bin, run the command

```
'which python'
```

to find out.

The 'No MTA' message means you are getting STDERR, which would normally get mailed to the user, but can't because you have no Mail Transfer Agent set up, like mailx, or mutt, so no mail for the user can get delivered from cron, so it is discarded. If you'd like STDERR to go into the log also, at the end, instead of

```
 "command" > test.out
```

write

```
 "command" 2>&1 > test.out
```

to redirect STDERR into STDOUT, then redirect both to test.out.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my cron to include the 2>&1 > test.out. How do I go in and view the test.out? I see it in my home directory but I don't know how to view the text.

Comment: Use whatever editor you are comfortable with. The fact that it's named test.out does not mean it is not a text file, it's just a text file you named test.out instead of test.txt. I prefer to use vim (vi) but, if you are using Crtl+x to save and exit, sounds like nano, so, in the directory where test.out is, type nano test.out. The file will be created in /home/ubuntu I believe, since you did not specify in cron. You can run 'find / -name test.out' to locate it.